# In graphql, is there a way to return data that satisfies all filters on parent and children?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

The structure of my query looks like

```
{
  parent(filter...){
    edges{
      node{
        field1
        child(filter...){
          edges{
            node{
              field2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the frontend, I will join parent with child and display in a table. E.g., if parent has three child, it will display three rows ("field1 child1_field2", "field1 child2_field2", "field1 child3_field2"). But if there is no child for that parent, I do not want to display that row at all. I know I can filter them out in the frontend. But with relay pagination, if I load 50 more parents, after filtering on child, there might be less than 50 rows left. As a result, it will render different number of rows on each "load more". Is there a way to return data that satisfies both parent's filter and child's filter. If not, what is the best way to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways by filtering on the back end (depending on your structure) before returning the data to the front end.  For example if you use a Java Stream in the back end, then do a stream.skip(start).limit(numResults).  If you use RxJava you can always apply a .filter() or .take(), etc

If possible you should combine the parent/child to a structure on the back end before sending it to the front end. If not you're going to end up making a ton of calls to the back end for each parent to see if it has children (until your required limit of '50' is met).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using graphene and flask as backend and the filter is already working. Actually, parent and child are two tables that have one-to-many relationship. How can I combine the parent/child to a flat structure?